# How to HTTP post a data to Node express API from a Arduino esp8226?

Tags: node.js, http, heroku, arduino, esp8266

I am HTTP Posting a data to web api https://morning-cliffs-85779.herokuapp.com/api/users from a arduino connected to esp8226. I am using wifiesp library to HTTP_POST a data.

When is post it the Arduino gives this response:

```
 Connected to server
 [WiFiEsp] Data packet send error (2)
 [WiFiEsp] Failed to write to socket 3
 [WiFiEsp] Disconnecting  3
```

And Heroku server gives response:

```
at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"
```

Below is the Arduino code:

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
      Serial.println("Connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request
    String content = "id=5bc58842bdfea0153bb27214&volt=7";
    client.println("POST /api/users HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: morning-cliffs-85779.herokuapp.com:80");// ("Host": host:port)
    client.println("Accept: */*");
    client.println("Content-Length: " + content.length());
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.println();
    client.println(content);
}
```

This is the node express API:

```
app.post('/api/users', function (req, res) {

    console.log('here');

    if (req.body.id) {
        DevReading.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, {
            volt: req.body.volt
        }, function (err, reading) {
            if (err) throw err;

            res.send('Update Success');
        });
    }

    else {

        var newDevReading = DevReading ({
            deviceName: 'test',
            volt: req.body.volt
        });

        newDevReading.save(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send('Reading Post Success');
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I answer this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67828007/how-can-i-send-get-or-post-request-to-heroku-api-using-esp8266/68732915#68732915

Answer (score 0):

Did it. Here's the code:

```
if (client.connectSSL(server, 443)) {
    Serial.println("Connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request
    String PostData = content + volt;
    Serial.println(PostData);
    client.println("POST /api/users HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: morning-cliffs-85779.herokuapp.com");
    client.println("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(PostData.length());
    client.println();
    client.println(PostData);
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
  Serial.println("Connected to server");
// Make a HTTP request
String content = "id=5bc58842bdfea0153bb27214&volt=7";
client.println("POST /api/users HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: morning-cliffs-85779.herokuapp.com:80");// ("Host": host:port)
client.println("Accept: */*");
client.println("Content-Length: " + content.length());
client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.println();
client.println(content);
client.println('\r\n\r\n');
```

}

it's better to add the next line after your metadata and after the content. you can see it here [httpServer](https://github.com/ncdcommunity/SHT31-temperature-and-humidity)